# Decrypt PreSignedUrl in AWS S3 using C#.Net for browsing images in browser

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I would like to decrypt the AWS S3 PreSignedUrl usng C#.Net and AmozonS3Client so that when I browse the url in browser, it should display the decrypted image file.

I tried files with both SSE and CSE encryption. With SSE encrypted file, when browse the PreSignedUrl, it shows SignatureNotMatch. The code to get Presigned Url I used is given below

```cs
GetPreSignedUrlRequest getPreSignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
  BucketName = bucketName,
  Key = string.Format("{0}", fileName),
  Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
  ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod = ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod.AES256,
  ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId = CustomerKey
};

urlString = client.GetPreSignedURL(getPreSignedUrlRequest);
```

With CSE, while browsing the PresignedUrl in browser, it says "Image file cannot be displayed because of errors on it". (I hope this is because the file is in encrypted mode)

Can anybody help me to find out a solution?

Comment: How are planning to use the Pre-Signed URL?

Comment: Planning to show in browser..as href to a tag

Comment: Is the file stored on the bucket is already encrypted?

Comment: yes it is using server side encryption

Comment: Did anyone find solution to this?

Comment: What I have noticed is that you combine CusomterMethod (SSE-C) with an KMS key id (SSE). I think this isn't possible. Furthermore, the KMS-Id is not the key itself, it's just the id to the key. Beside that, you can't use a SSE-C presigned URL directly. You must send some headers (method, key, etc) to the server (not possible with normal a-href). So I don't think that you can (or should) use SSE-C for this purpose (as the key must be public then).

Comment: And another side note - 5 minutes will not be enough for images on websites. If your image is way down at the bottom of a page, some browser will load the image only if its near the current viewport. So if you stay on top of the page for 5 minutes and then scroll down, the image won't be loaded. ;)

Comment: And you should use `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(..)` for `Expires`. Because the expire date is always UTC, but you server could be another timezone. :)